# 16bit wine application has red background

Tags: wine

I'm trying to run an old Win 3.1 program on Wine, latest on ubuntu 19.10 (also testing on 18.04).

It works OK but the background is all red, so makes all images look funny. I think it's supposed to be white?

Any ideas? using WINEARCH=win32 and trying all windows versions from 3.1 to windows 10, all behave the same. I unchecked window manager window decoration and control. It's supposed to look like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Rtjujfhfcc

But looks like:

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot? - that may help to figure out what it is.

Comment: @JonasCz-ReinstateMonica Please see new edit